# ggplot2でannotate内のlabelで指定した日本語が文字化けする

Tags: r, ggplot2

stackoverflowもRも初心者です。

```
 ggplot(data = mpg,mapping = aes(x = displ,y = cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate(geom = "point", x = add_x, y = add_y, colour = "red") +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = c(5,5), y = c(30,25), label = c("要チェック!", "赤色のデータを追加"))
```

こちらで文字化けしてしまい、ぐぐって

```
theme_set( theme_bw(base_family = "HiraKakuProN-W3"))
```

などを事前に設定していているのですが、それでも文字化けいたします。

環境：

- mac OS Catalina 10.15.4
- RStudio version 1.2.5042
- R version 3.6.0

よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

あ・・・できてしまった。
データフレームの変数からマップされるわけじゃないので、
annotateの中にfamilyを設定しないといけないんですね。

```
ggplot(data = mpg,mapping = aes(x = displ,y = cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate(geom = "point", x = add_x, y = add_y, colour = "red") +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = c(5,5), y = c(30,25), label = c("要チェック！", "赤色のデータを追加"), family = "HiraKakuProN-W3")
```

cf.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083700/how-to-have-annotated-text-style-to-inherit-from-theme-set-options